# Divide members of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation system:

$dx/dt = x[0.5(1 - y)]$

$dy/dt = y[-0.5(1 - x)]$

can i rightfully divide it's members to get:
$dx/dy = \frac{x(1-y)}{y(x-1)}$?

Comment: Yes you can.  This comes from the chain rule.

Comment: And i can do this without worry if dy/dt becomes zero somewhere?

Comment: Well, sure, you have to exclude those cases.